# Drawing a line Between Widgets

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

In my Flutter application, I want to connect two arbitrary boxes with a line.
The example shows two *MyBoxes* in a `GridView`.

[image: MyBoxes]

I want to swipe from MyBox on the left to MyBox on the right and draw a line in the space between them to show the connection.
However, I couldn't find a way to draw lines beyond the widget border.

Is there a way to do this with drawing tricks like CustomPainter, or with changes to the widget's structure?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I thought that this might be a nice challenge, so I just created a minimum viable example using [`CustomPainter`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomPainter-class.html). Personally, I would always use a custom [`RenderObject`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/RenderObject-class.html) using [`LeafRenderObjectWidget`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LeafRenderObjectWidget-class.html) and [`RenderBox`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/RenderBox-class.html), however, **`CustomPainter`**'s are supposed to be easier, which is why I will use it for this example.

The basic idea is having a [`Stack`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) that contains both your boxes and the `CustomPainter`, which allows you to draw beyond the constraints of any single widget. In my example, I do not straighten the lines and do not ensure that they connect two boxes, however, you could easily add this by supplying [`GlobalKey`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GlobalKey-class.html)'s to your boxes, storing these keys in a global list (e.g. in an [`InheritedWidget`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html) or Provider) and then applying some logic to the positions returned by [`(globalKey.currentContext.findRenderObject() as RenderBox).localToGlobal(Offset.zero)`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/RenderBox/localToGlobal.html). You can also access the size of your boxes like this using [`globalKey.currentContext.size`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BuildContext/size.html).
This, however, would be a bit too much for an answer, which is why I will only share code for the basic context of drawing lines between two widgets:

#### [Source code as a Gist](https://gist.github.com/creativecreatorormaybenot/a984d3a64f9ce5362cd31fe6bb585d43)

[image: Illustration]

Comment: Thank you for your wonderful idea and knowledge.
The combination of `Stack` and `CustomPainter` is very useful to me.
I want to draw a line using the location of MyBox, so I'm currently trying to use `GlobalKey` to access the location information.
I will mark this answer as soon as we succeed. (I am currently dealing with the error of `Duplicate GlobalKey`.)

Comment: @Msyk Right, as every `MyBox` should be unique, you will have to make the `GlobalKey` unique (otherwise you would not be able to get a distinct widget from your `GlobalKey`). You could e.g. use indexes to differentiate between different boxes.

Comment: I'm Successful. I saved the Indices of the concatenated MyBox in `InheritsWidget` and drew the line by calculating the Grid size and coordinates from `GlobalKey` given to `GridView`. and, I also learned how Flutter works with `Key` and I fully understood the structure. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Mysk A complete sample code would be much appreciated. Can you please share the code in github or somewhere please? I am having difficult time to get the widget at the drag start position and drag end position of the line. If somehow I was able to find the position of those widgets then I could draw a line connecting them.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot Can you please share the code too? I can't resist to upvote this answer but on the other side I feel it's half an answer.

Comment: @Shuji Here you go: https://gist.github.com/creativecreatorormaybenot/a984d3a64f9ce5362cd31fe6bb585d43

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot This is the same code that you have shared in your answer.  Actually I am having difficult time to get the widget at the drag start position and drag end position of the line. If somehow I was able to find the position of those widgets then I could draw a line connecting them.