# Drawing a line Between Widgets and make the lines clickable

Tags: flutter, dart, line, clickable, gesturedetector

I'm referring to this issue right here: [Drawing a line Between Widgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57159085/drawing-a-line-between-widgets) that have been already solved, but I have additional question about it.

I want to make the lines in the Stack widget clickable, but with **GestureDetector** widget it is not possible.

Do you have any solutions for me on how can I solve the problem. I would highly appreciate your answer guys!

Screenshot below:
[image]

Comment: What issue are you having that's preventing you from doing it with a `GestureDetector`?

Comment: When I put the the line (which is built with CustomPaint) inside of the GestureDetector, it isn't becoming clickable. I want to make the line clickable so that if users click on the line the software can make an action (e.g. delete the line...)

Comment: user container inside gesturedetector else InkWell

Comment: I have updated my issue with a screenshot. I think now you can understand what my problem is...

Answer (score 0):

try this:-

```
GestureDetector(
    onTap: (){
      //do your code on click
      },
      child: Container(
          width: 20,
          height: double.infinity,
          color: Colors.grey,
      ),
    )
```

Comment: did you try InkWell

Comment: The problem is with Stack widget. It doesn't let the Container inside the GestureDetector position where the line is.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `GestureDetector` with the `behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent` for it to be detectable with the `CustomPaint`.

Comment: You're saying that your `print` statement is not being printed when you tap using this behavior? That's weird, as it should.

Comment: No, it doesn't print the statement! That's why I am posting the issue. Try it on your own...